# How can I tell the source of pointer argument?

Tags: c++

```
int a;
int *b;
void test(int* target)
{
    delete(target);
}
test(new int); // <-- It's ok, of course.
test(&a); // <-- It raises assertion fail, of course, too.
```

Given following code aboved. Only thing I know about the `target` is an pointer to integer. How can I tell the source of argument pointer?

Comment: What do you mean by the source?

Comment: You have no visibility into how something was allocated.  It's up to you to keep track.

Comment: You can't do that reliably at all. This is why manual memory management is complicated - and best avoided -, otherwise you could just throw around `if (safe_to_delete(ptr)) delete ptr;` and be happy.

Comment: It was allocated by CrAzYmAlLoC on 6th September 2013, 6:03pm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell reliably whether a pointer points to the beginning of a valid dynamically allocated portion of memory.

That is why manual memory management is complicated in the first place - for everything that you allocate dynamically, you need to properly define who is responsible for creating and who is responsible for deleting. Getting this wrong leads to undefined behaviour, segfaults, and all other kinds of hard-to-trace bugs.

Remember though that C++ gives you a lot of tools (RAII, smart pointers, ...) that make manual memory management unneccessary except for a few remaining cases.